# How to call custom query URL using Restangular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular, loopbackjs

I want to call URL with special charecters in query parameter using Restangular `customGET` method. I am using Loopback for my API, which uses square brackets for query. It seems it's not allowed in Restangular.

I want to call following URL.

```
/api/v1/employees/findOne?filter[where][salesCode]=SC2
```

or this but not sure how.

```
/api/v1/employees?filter[where][salesCode]=SC2
```

I tried following with no success.

```
Restangular.all("employees").customGET("findOne", {filter + "%5Bwhere%5D%5BsalesCode%5D": newValue});
```

and

```
Restangular.all("employees").customGET("findOne", {filter[where][salesCode]: newValue});
```

As a work around I am using `$http` but a hack is a hack end of the day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should do:

```
Restangular.all("employees").customGET("findOne", {"filter[where][salesCode]": newValue});
```

That should do it :).